# Why this @Transactional doesn't work with rollback operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hello StackOverflow community! I have problem with @Transactional. It doesn't work properly in my scenario.

How can I rollback

```
JobOffer jobOffer = jobOfferRepository.save(JobOffer.builder().id(UUID.randomUUID()).build());
```

```
@GetMapping("/loadLinks")
public ResponseEntity<?> loadLinks(){

    List<String> allLinks = List.of("https://my-domain-sobs.com/pl/job/mid-dev");

    for (String singleLink : allLinks) {

        saveLink(singleLink);

    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}


@Transactional(rollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public void saveLink(String singleLink) {
    try{

        JobOffer jobOffer = jobOfferRepository.save(JobOffer.builder().id(UUID.randomUUID()).build());

        JobLink jobLink = JobLink.builder()
                .jobLink(singleLink)
                .jobOffer(jobOffer)
                .isProcessed(false)
                .category("Kotlin")
                .id(UUID.randomUUID())
                .timeOfAddition(LocalDateTime.now())
                .remote(true)
                .build();
        jobLinkRepository.save(jobLink);

    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("Exception occured during saving link!");
    }

}
```

Here

```
jobLinkRepository.save(jobLink);
```

I am getting exception and after in catch I am throwning new DataIntegrityViolationException. On the top of my method I am using Transactional with rollbackFor but it doesn't work. JobOffer is alwayes saved.

I am using

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

Comment: see point #1 here https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-transactional-mistakes-everyone-did-31418e5a6d6b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactional method must be in separate class.

You can check this : https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring